# Test DynamoDB get promise with JUnit

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, testing, junit, aws-lambda

I'm trying to test my AWS Lambda handler that makes a `get()` call to DynamoDB using a promise.

```
const DynamoDB = require('aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb')

const documentClient = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

module.exports.handler = () => {
    const params = {
        Key: {
            testKey: { S: 'testKey' },
        },
        TableName: 'test',
    }

    return documentClient.get(params).promise()
}
```

I want to mock the `get()` call to DynamoDB using JUnit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way that I now test this function is below. We want to mock the dynamodb client within the `aws-sdk`, specifically the DocumentClient, which is a function that returns a promise.

```
const promise = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('test')
const mockGet = jest.fn(() => ({ promise }))

jest.mock('aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb', () => ({
    DocumentClient: jest.fn(() => ({
        get: mockGet,
    })),
}))

const DynamoDB = require('aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb')

const documentClient = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

const { handler } = require('./stackoverflow')

it('should return test item from dynamodb', async () => {
    const item = await handler()

    const params = { Key: { testKey: { S: 'testKey' } }, TableName: 'test' }

    expect(documentClient.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(params)
    expect(documentClient.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

    expect(item).toEqual('test')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at using [DynamoDB Local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html) instead of mocking DynamoDB. You get the benefit of knowing your SDK calls are valid (since DynamoDB Local validates requests just like real DynamoDB) and you don't have to worry about the complications of mocking requests with realistic-looking responses that may not accurately reflect how real DynamoDB would respond.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion. I did think of using localstack or similar. But ideally I don't want to be spinning up a local instance of dynamo for unit tests to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sinon` to stub any `function`

Example stub function `getDatabyId` of Db services.

```
const chai = require('chai');
const sandbox = require('sinon').createSandbox();
const expect = chai.expect;
const dbService = require('../util/models/dbService').dbService;
const BPromise = require('bluebird');

 it('Should return success', function (done) {
    sandbox.stub(dbService, 'getDatabyId').returns(BPromise.resolve());
    .....
  });
```